# Java: "error: cannot access" the interface

Tags: java

So I have this `Annotator` interface:

```
public interface Annotator {
    String getViewName();

    View getView(TextAnnotation var1) throws AnnotatorException;

    String[] getRequiredViews();
}
```

which is extended by `GazetteerViewGenerator`:

```
public class GazetteerViewGenerator extends Annotator {
    public static final GazetteerViewGenerator gazetteersInstance;
    ...
```

The issue is that when I create an object of `GazetteerViewGenerator` and cast into `Annotator` it gives me errors, which is really weird:

```
public class MyCuratorClient {
    public static Annotator gazetteers = (Annotator) GazetteerViewGenerator.gazetteersInstance;
    ...
```

and here is the error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project Illinois-Combined-Coref: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /Users/danielk/ideaProjects/Illinois-Combined-Coref/src/main/java/edu/illinois/cs/cogcomp/lbj/coref/util/MyCuratorClient.java:[25,38] error: cannot access Annotator
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A java class `implements` an interface rather than `extends` it.

You should have used this class definition:

```
public class GazetteerViewGenerator implements Annotator {
    public static final GazetteerViewGenerator gazetteersInstance;
    ... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As to the "Cannot access..." error, I found that intelliJ has a blocking bug preventing you refreshing from changed packaging. It's possible that your code has no issue at all but is underlined with wiggly red lines in IDE. Try to re-open the project again and your problem may be solved with **no change**.